# Who Dropped MYSQL Table

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6

I am using Mysql 5.7 and 2-days back someone drop my table. I didn't enable my general log. How can i find the username who dropped the table?

Comment: Welcome to the site , By default, the server writes files for all enabled logs in the data directory. Did you checked that.

Comment: Did you have the binlog turned on?

Comment: yes. Its configure for replication.

Answer (score 0):

By default MySQL doesnot log general SQL statements. Configure MySQL to do so. The MySQL documentation on logging (MySQL :: MySQL 5.1 Reference Manual :: 5.2 MySQL Server Logs) should help you do that.

Comment: Unfortunately, i didn't enable general log when the table was dropped. From which server logs i can get my desired information